# How can I create a class instance from a list Python

Tags: python, string, class, instance, python-2.6

I'm making a program for a school project. It's a Model United Nations.

```
countries = ['Australia', 'Brazil', 'Canada']

class delegate(object):
   def __init__(self, country):
     self.country = country
```

I have a list with countries and a class called delegate. So, each delegate object must have a country. Normally I would do it like this:

```
mexico = delegate('Mexico')
```

And that would be it. But I would like to loop over the country list and create class instances for each. I mean:

```
australia = delegate('Australia')
brazil = delegate('Brazil')
canada = delegate('Canada')
```

and so on. 
**How can I make this?** 
Thank you very much!!

Comment: I would suggest you re-assess your selection for the answer that helped you. Or at least explain the reasoning why that answer helped you achieve what you are looking for? Currently [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44981035/1832539) answer hits exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @idjaw Hi, I'm new on Python (also programming) and I tried the answer you indicated and it shows an error, the one I chose did not. I didn't know why, but if you can explain me I'll be glad in changing my chose. Actually, I had. 
This the error it shows:
delegates = {country: Delegate(country) for country in countries} 
^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I just copy pasted the code and I did not receive a syntax error. I suggest you copy the code and paste it in to a new python file with nothing else and try again to make sure.

Comment: I have tried that. Maybe the version? I'm using python 2.6

Comment: Specifying the version would have helped people answering the question to provide an answer more relevant to your environment. I currently don't have a 2.6 installed on my end. But that would explain it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Creating named variables from a list is usually a bad idea. Maybe you could try

```
countries = ['Australia', 'Brazil', 'Canada']

class Delegate(object):    # according to PEP8, class names should be title-case
    def __init__(self, country):
        self.country = country

# create a dict
delegates = {country: Delegate(country) for country in countries}
```

**Edit:** as per @SethMMorton, Python 2.6 does not understand dictionary comprehensions (ie what I used above). You can get the same result using

```
delegates = dict([(country, Delegate(country)) for country in countries])
```

Comment: nit: py3 note for not *needing* to inherit from object explicitly - > `class Delegate:` should suffice.

Comment: I don't understand the dict and when I write it into the program it shows a syntax error.
delegates = {country: Delegate(country) for country in countries}
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Arturo.Mart what version of Python are you using? This works perfectly for me in Python 3.5.3.

Comment: @HughBothwell They are using Python 2.6 (as mentioned in the comments of the question).  For that version there are no `dict` comprehensions so you might want to mention that `dict([(country, Delegate(country)) for country in countries])` will work for < Python 2.7.

Comment: @HughBothwell I'm using Python 2.6 So if anyone can help me with this I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

```
[delegate(c) for c in countries]
```

Answer (score -3):

I believe you're looking for what's called an anonymous class. This means you're making a class without assigning it to a variable. For example:

```
country_delegates = []
for country in countries:
    country_delegates.append(delegate(country))
```

This creates a list of delegate objects, one for each country. If you want to get the delegate belonging to a specific country, you could write a function that searches that list and returns the delegate object for the correct country.

Comment: You aren't making an anonymous class here.  You aren't making any class *at all*. I suppose you could torture the `type` constructor to create an "anonymous class", but even then, not really...

Comment: It's very unfortunate this got accepted which ends up providing very misleading guidance to future readers.

Comment: Could you elaborate? If you have a class called `delegate` this code works fine. I thought an anonymous class was a class instantiated without being assigned to a variable, is that not right?